# A regex that works in `find`

Tags: regex, unix, find, bsd

I have a directory with ~8000 files of the form

```
output/Manuscript_00750_AnimalGiants-compact.json
output/Manuscript_00750_AnimalGiants-expanded.json
output/Manuscript_00750_AnimalGiants.json
output/Manuscript_00752_AnimalGiants-compact.json
output/Manuscript_00752_AnimalGiants-expanded.json
output/Manuscript_00752_AnimalGiants.json
output/Unit_TZH_12345_Foo-compact.json
output/Unit_TZH_12345_Foo-expanded.json
output/Unit_TZH_12345_Foo.json
```

I need to come up with a regex to work with the `find` tool to select just the Manuscript-compact ones:

```
output/Manuscript_00750_AnimalGiants-compact.json
output/Manuscript_00752_AnimalGiants-compact.json
```

Coming up with the regex is the easy part, but getting `find` to cooperate is the hard part.

Here's my regex:

```
/Manuscript[0-9_a-zA-Z]+-compact\.json/
```

Here are some of the commands I've tried; all produce zero results. The cwd is the directory above `output/`:

```
find output -regex "Manuscript[0-9_a-zA-Z]+-compact\.json"
find output -regex "\./output/Manuscript[0-9_a-zA-Z]+-compact\.json/"
find output -regex ".*\Manuscript[0-9_a-zA-Z]+-compact.*\json"
```

But this command does produce results - it selects all the files that start with "Manuscript", which is obviously too broad:

```
find output -regex ".*\Manuscript.*\json"
```

What's the correct regex format for `find` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On OSX you can use this `find` with extended regex:

```
find -E output -regex '.*/Manuscript[0-9_a-zA-Z]+-compact\.json$'
```

On gnu `find` use:

```
find output -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/Manuscript[0-9_a-zA-Z]+-compact\.json$'
```

Comment: The first one works - thanks! Can you explain why though? What's with the `'.*/` at the beginning?

Comment: `.*/Manuscript `matches 0 or more characters before slash and  `Manuscript`. Even when this file is in current directory there will be `./` before `Manuscript`

Comment: For reference, the `-E` option is derived from FreeBSD, and should work in NetBSD, DragonflyBSD, but perhaps not OpenBSD.

Comment: @commanda: You may consider accepting this answer :)